# how to capture only one part of the getrawtransaction

Tags: client, php

I want to capture just one part of what Getrawtransaction returns, but it returns an array within an array that i can't seem to process.

I.e when

> $txid =
> '4f52e7769fe23059a4f0fa2b66ca0ba9595812654b90cc0526ddb9703a3e1b33';
>
> $txidarray = ($rpc->getrawtransaction($txid,1));

then I can grab the whole "vout" array element(s) with  :

> print_r($txidarray[vout])

;

i.e that returns :

```
> Array (
>     [0] => Array
>         (
>             [value] => 0.077
>             [n] => 0
>             [scriptPubKey] => Array
>                 (
>                     [asm] => OP_DUP OP_HASH160 efe11230ccff2380c3115e2826098931bb76ccef OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG
>                     [hex] => 76a914efe11230ccff2380c3115e2826098931bb76ccef88ac
>                     [reqSigs] => 1
>                     [type] => pubkeyhash
>                     [addresses] => Array
>                         (
>                             [0] => 1NsN84QPXSXEdojiC482PnJUGNfx9XduQ6
>                         )
> 
>                 )
> 
>         )
> 
>     [1] => Array
>         (
>             [value] => 0.02636684
>             [n] => 1
>             [scriptPubKey] => Array
>                 (
>                     [asm] => OP_DUP OP_HASH160 ae57d86c288389e086eadf1bc50998d86ad2828a OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG
>                     [hex] => 76a914ae57d86c288389e086eadf1bc50998d86ad2828a88ac
>                     [reqSigs] => 1
>                     [type] => pubkeyhash
>                     [addresses] => Array
>                         (
>                             [0] => 1Gtqoz4tNTLYBR13AxypwsXupsevcy5QPq
>                         )
> 
>                 )
```

But how can i grab ONLY  "1Gtqoz4tNTLYBR13AxypwsXupsevcy5QPq"  ???

I just want to get that address from the getrawtransaction for an txid !!

I tried :

> print_r($txidarray[vout,0,scriptkey[0]);

but does not work, no clue as to what the correct syntax is !! anyone can help me ? many thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're indexing the array incorrectly.

Try:

```
print_r($txidarray[vout][1][scriptPubKey][addresses][0]);
```